# Error on deploying .Net Core 2.0 Web API to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings

I have used **.Net Core 2.0 to** build my **Web API**. Now I am trying to deploy this project to **AWS** using its **Elastic Beanstalk** Service. I am also using the **Visual Studios AWS deployment tool**.

During the deployment process, I am receiving the following error;

> Error during deployment: Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\appsettings.Development.json'.

I have added the following section into my `.csproj`;

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I can see that my `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` are in my output folder when I build my project. Also they appear in the published directory if I publish the app into my local pc.

I could not understand why does Amazon's service can not pick it up...

**Edit:** So, interestingly I created a new **.Net Core 2.0 Web Api** project from Visual Studio templates and tried deploying it to AWS and it gave me the same error. However when I create an MVC project and deploy it to AWS everything works fine. The default settings for the web api template seems to be effecting the deployment somehow...

Comment: Did you have to add `aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json` file and `web.config` to the project before deployment? I am using AWS VS toolkit to do the deployment too and simply got an error saying "There is an error in starting up your application"...

Comment: @stt106 No, I did not need to add anything to my configuration file specific to AWS. I would suggest you to first deploy your application to your local host and see if there is any other problems before deploying it to AWS.

Comment: local deployment works fine; I also had it deployed to azure which also works fine but couldn't get it working on aws. Which version of window server did you choose on aws? A few months ago (before core 2.0 was released) I deployed core 1.1 to aws using win2012 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @stt106 I have deployed my application on a `64bit Windows Server 2016 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0`. AWS started supporting .Net Core 2.0 a month ago, therefore I believe its errors are misleading. This situation is obviously a bug if I am not able to deploy a fresh Visual Studio project to AWS. All I can suggest to you is using my work around. If your project is not huge, just create an MVC template and merge your project with that project that should work.

Comment: ok thanks will try that. Just to be sure, you didn't do anything mentioned in this https://neelbhatt40.wordpress.com/2017/08/23/net-core-2-0-deployment-on-aws/ ?

Comment: @stt106 the link provided shows how to add an AWS Configuration file to your project which is not required. Since you are using AWS VS toolkit, at the end of the deployment there will be an option to add an AWS Configuration script which is the same one on that link. You can easily test and see that it is not required by creating an empty MVC project and deploy it to AWS without touching anything. It shall work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created a new **.Net Core 2.0 MVC Project** and migrated/adapted my web api to it. Now its deployed without any issues.

So if your project was started from a Web Api template and getting a simillar error, try switching between templates.

Answer (score 1):

So after trial and error with including and excluding certain files, the problem is with WebApi because it does not have a wwwroot folder and it would appear the elastic beanstalk scripts are looking for this.

To make it work, I added a wwwroot folders and put a placeholder html file inside it and my project now deploys correctly!

Comment: I've tried this, but I still get error deploying.  Is there anything else at all you did? Could you update your answer with the Startup.cs and Program.cs for reference/comparison please? - p.s great name!

Answer (score -2):

Are you using AWS toolkit for VS 2017 to deploy your application. That would do a lot of the config work for you.

There are many problems with the AWS preconfigured environment for asp.net core  2 with IIS 10, try terminating your beanstalk environment and recreate and deploy through AWS toolkit directly from Visual Studio. Right click your project and use the "Publish to AWS Beanstalk"

Comment: As it is stated on my question **I am also using the Visual Studios AWS deployment tool.**